# Update status column where status is null

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Anyone can help in query

I want to fetch one by one record from startdate to enddate in the table and update one by one record from the table

Like I am having one table **Temp**

```
ID   DATE          Status
1    2011-09-10      WO
2    2011-09-11      WO
3    2011-09-12     NULL
4    2011-09-13     NULL
5    2011-09-14     NULL
6    2011-09-15      H
```

Now i need the output like below **when i used give startDate and enddate then Status which have NULL value should get 'L'**

```
ID   DATE          Status
1    2011-09-10      WO
2    2011-09-11      WO
3    2011-09-12       L
4    2011-09-13       L
5    2011-09-14       L
6    2011-09-15      H
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have to do this "one by one"?

```
UPDATE dbo.Temp SET Status = 'L' WHERE Status IS NULL;
```